# VScode doesnt see pyenv python interpreters

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I installed `pyenv-win` on my windows machine. It works fine in the command line. I can install python versions, set them as global etc. But My VS Code doesn't see them. It only sees one python interpreter I installed a long time ago when I wasn't using pyenv yet.

VScode:
[image]

pyenv:

```
C:\Users\jbron\cmder
λ pyenv versions
  3.7.0
* 3.8.0 (set by C:\Users\jbron\.pyenv\pyenv-win\version)
```

Why is it not finding my pyenv interpreters? I don't have problems like that on my Linux machines

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? It's crazy that VS Code relies on the official Python installer on windows instead of the available `python` on path.

Comment: It's been 2 years and 10 months, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you try the following:

1. Please check whether the Python environment variable contains your installed Python path:

   [image]
2. Please reopen VSCode after installation:

   [image]

Update:

The environment variable path of "pyenv" I use is: (Under this path, we can find Python 3.6.7 downloaded by pyenv)

[image]

[image]

We can see the storage location where it downloaded `Python 3.6.7`:

```
 C:\Users\...\.pyenv\pyenv-win\install_cache\python-3.6.7-amd64-webinstall.exe
```

Double-click to install:

[image]

Comment: It does not. I know that. But is there a way on windows to have that working? Because the point of pyenv is that you can freely manage your python versions. It works this way on Linux and it recognizes them. The only way to have them show up in Windows is to add them separately by env variables?

Comment: @John -I checked "Add Python3.6 to PATH" when installing Python, and then it will be automatically added to the environment variable.

Comment: The point here is that I'm using pyenv-win to install python interpreters. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: @John -How did you install Python using "pyenv-win"? Is there this Python path in the environment variable after installation? When the Python environment variable is correct, VSCode can recognize it.

Comment: Like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vG2yWK87TCY&ab_channel=Exosfeer

Comment: @John  -Does the 'cmd' window output its version number when you enter "_pyenv_"? I updated my answer and you could refer to it.

Comment: @JillCheng You're missing the point. Using a Python MSI installer so that VS Code detects it makes using pyenv-win useless. OP is trying to find a way to tell VS Code "hey use the  `python` interpreter available in the path, which is set by py-env-win automatically when switching the global python version.