# Python does not run command

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple command in a .py file on Visual Studio Code, namely:

```
import os
```

I get the following return in the terminal:

```
& : The term 'C:/Users/Tim-S/anaconda3/envs/plotlyenv/python.exe' is not recognized as 
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:/Users/Tim-S/anaconda3/envs/plotlyenv/python.exe "c:/Users/Tim-S/ ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/Tim-S/...yenv/python.exe:String) 
[], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone explain me how I can solve this?

Comment: Looks like python is not installed or not on the path.

Comment: Windows can't find `C:/Users/Tim-S/anaconda3/envs/plotlyenv/python.exe`, which appears to be what it's trying to use to run your code.

Comment: Ok, so what shall I change it to? Or what is a normal path to install it on so to say?

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) or [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python). Then, in your terminal (cmd, powershell, windows terminal, etc.), run python. Only then, should you attempt to run anything in VS Code.

You may already be having success up to that point, but it isn't clear from your question. I can see you have some environment (anaconda) installed. There are several VS Code plugins for Python. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65574153/2081835) may help you further with that part.

[Here is the Windows port of pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win), which is an excellent version management tool, which may also be of use.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. The strange thing is that I can run jupyter notebook in visual code, but whenever I want to run a python file by running it in the terminal I get this strange error. I will try to take the steps that are mentioned in the link that you posted and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a virtual environment: by the looks of the path in the error - 'C:/Users/Tim-S/anaconda3/envs/plotlyenv/python.exe'

seems like you are trying to do so. IF that's the case:

- Possible it did not get installed properly and hence cannot find the python file
- you have to reinstall it and activate the environment

But that will solve the problem partially

> After activating virtual environment, you have to install the library
> that you are going to use

What I can see from your problem statement and file path you will need to install os and plotly

```
pip install os

pip install plotly - if required
```